# How to return a XML file using JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb

I have a school work where I need to use the JAXB framework to return a xml that I have on a folder on my machine. The XML folder that I need to return is the following one and I have to do it on java language.

```
<bookstore>
<book category="cooking">
<title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
<author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
<year>2005</year>
<price>30.00</price>
</book>
<book category="children">
<title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
<author>J K. Rowling</author>
<year>2005</year>
<price>29.99</price>
</book>
<book category="web">
<title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
<author>James McGovern</author>
<author>Per Bothner</author>
<author>Kurt Cagle</author>
<author>James Linn</author>
<author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
<year>2003</year>
<price>49.99</price>
</book>
<book category="web" cover="paperback">
<title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
<author>Erik T. Ray</author>
<year>2003</year>
<price>39.95</price>
</book>
</bookstore>
```

Believe me I tried to find a answer for my work by watching a lot of tutorials and the official oracle docs but I didn't had any sucess.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build a Java object in an XML string, obtain an instance of the **JAXBContext** class, for the use of the **JAXB AP**I since it provides methods to disarm, sort and validate operations. Then get the Marshaller instance of **JAXBContext**. The *marshal()*, method generates the Java object in XML, and then the XML object can be written to any ways. For example:

```
import java.io.StringWriter;    
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

public class JAXBTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Book book = new Book("Everyday Italian", 2005);
        generateXML(book);
    }

    private static final void generateXML(Book book) {
        try {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Book.class);
            Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            marshaller.marshal(book, stringWriter);
            System.out.println(stringWriter.toString());

        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<book>
    <title>Everyday Italian</title>
    <year>2005</year>
</book>
```